# Update html element with knockout js binding

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-mobile-listview

I want to update ui with knockout js binding. I am able to update list but changes are not getting reflected in ui. I am getting following error :

```
Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

Following is my code:
When I check the length of array, alert shows array is updated but I want the changes to be reflected in ui also.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>

var Person = [ {
    name : "qwe qwe",
    number : 123123123
}, {
    name : "asd asd",
    number : 999999999
} ];

var myVM = function() {
    this.persons = ko.observableArray(Person);
}

function init() {   
alert(Person.length);
    ko.applyBindings(new myVM());   
}

function AddPerson()
{
PushToArray(Person,"name","123");
init();
}

function PushToArray(array, var1, var2) {
    array.push({
        name : var1,
        number : var2
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
            <div>
                <button onclick="AddPerson()">Add</button>              
                    <div data-bind="foreach:persons">
                        <p data-bind="text:name"> </p>
                    </div>                      
            </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont need to call ko.applyBindings(new myVM()) when you add a person,it should be done only once

Comment: Thanks man, your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ko.applyBindings()` function has to be called only once. From then every change you make to the observable objects in the viewmodel  will be automatically reflected  in the guy.

Just remove the call to the  `init();` function inside your `AddPerson()` function and  call it only once from somewhere else and that should fix the problem

Comment: Sorry it was not clear that after you remove the init() you still have to call it from somewhere else, but only once.